# React Native: Popular library which supports image cropping without zoom in/out feature

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, cropper

Currently I am using react-native-image-crop-picker which works very fine for cropping the image in iOS. But I would like to prevent the zoom in/out feature. Unfortunately it is not supported in this library.

My requirement is,

1. Launch cropping window in 4:5 ratio
2. Should not allow user to zoom in/out
3. User can move the cropping window over the image and can resize the cropping window. But it should in 4:5 ratio

Kindly suggest any other popular library which satisfy above requirement

Answer (score 0):

> iOS/Android image picker with support for camera, video, configurable
>   compression, multiple images and cropping 
>   https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker

Comment: OP is looking for an alternative library compared to react-native-image-crop-picker. The limitations are mentioned above

Comment: Did you try to open an issue in GitHub? https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker

Comment: Yes, already raised question for disabling zoom in/out (https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/issues/1160) and setting cropping window in specified ratio (https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/issues/686)